# I want to insert date into my SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Type of date : `datetime2`

```
INSERT INTO Event_test (date, Object, ASDU, IOA)
VALUES(10/07/2016 12:00:00.523, TMC1DEFCAL, 65, 408)
```

Syntax error near '12'

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need single quotes.  I would also recommend ISO standard formats:

```
INSERT INTO Event_test (date, Object, ASDU, IOA)
    VALUES('2016-10-07T12:00:00.523', 'TMC1DEFCAL', 65, 408);
```

Single quotes are also needed for string values.

Comment: why is it shown as `07/10/2016 12:00` instead of  `07/10/2016 12:00:00.523` ??

Comment: Where are you seeing that @AhmedAekbj

Answer (score 1):

Use ISO format date with single quotes. It should work.

```
INSERT INTO Event_test (date, Object, ASDU, IOA) VALUES
    ('2016-10-07 12:00:00.523', 'TMC1DEFCAL', 65, 408);
```